# Javascript : array.length returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a set of data that is being passed on by the PHP's `json_encode` function. I'm using the jQuery `getJSON` function to decode it:

```
$.getJSON("url", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The output looks like this in the console:

```
Object {1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object, 8: Object, 9: Object, 10: Object}
```

I can access each array by using `data[1]`, `data[2]` etc, but to make it easier I thought of looping thought it so I can access all at once:

```
$.getJSON("url", function (data) {
    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

However I can't get this to work because the `data.length` returns the value `undefined`. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: That isn't an array. It is an object. You can't loop through objects like you can arrays.

Comment: It's object not an array

Comment: Try `Object.keys(data).length`

Comment: Looks as though it's not an array but an arbitrary object.  If you have control over the PHP serialization, you might be able to change that.

Comment: +1 to what Scott said: it's quite easy to turn this into a real array, replacing your `json_encode($something)` with `json_encode(array_values($something))`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet if you can post that as an answer I can mark it as correct

Comment: @rksh: I know this is an old question, but I was wondering if you could have a look at it again, in regards to the accepted answer ;-)

Answer (score 89):

Objects don't have a `.length` property.

A simple solution if you know you don't have to worry about `hasOwnProperty` checks, would be to do this:

```
Object.keys(data).length;
```

If you *have* to support IE 8 or lower, you'll have to use a loop, instead:

```
var length= 0;
for(var key in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        length++;
    }
}
```

Comment: for [IE >= 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 31):

One option is:

```
Object.keys(myObject).length
```

Sadly it not works under older IE versions (under 9).

If you need that compatibility, use the painful version:

```
var key, count = 0;
for(key in myObject) {
  if(myObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: saved me a great time after all those years, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It looks as though it's not an array but an arbitrary object. If you have control over the PHP serialization, you might be able to change that.

As **[raina77ow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229023/raina77ow)** [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552402/javascript-array-length-returns-undefined?noredirect=1#comment32548015_21552402), one way to do this in PHP would be by replacing something like this:

```
json_encode($something)
```

with something like:

```
json_encode(array_values($something))
```

But don't ignore the other answers here about `Object.keys`.  They should also accomplish what you want if you don't have the ability or the desire to change the serialization of your object.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Object.keys(data).length
```

If IE < 9, you can loop through the object yourself with a for loop

```
var len = 0;
var i;

for (i in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        len++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy fix to this question is to add '[' in the start of your json file, and ending it with a ']'. This solved it for me.